# How to store a series data retrieved into an object?

Tags: angular, typescript

In this project I'm trying to store the data such as room type, rate type, rate code into an object called `this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_code][rate_type] = {}` when `onCountChange(action, room_index, stateroom_index)`(increases the count of unit when button pressed) function is executed. However, not only did the storage of data into the object not work, the `onCountChange()` function stopped working as well. Any fixes? I've provided a code snippet below. Thank you

```
onCountChange(action, room_index, stateroom_index) {
        
        let rate_code = this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_code];
        let rate_type = this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_type];
 
        this.arrSelection.main = {room_index};
        this.arrSelection.rates = {stateroom_index};
        if (!this.arrSelection.main) this.arrSelection.main = {}
        if (!this.arrSelection.main.rates) this.arrSelection.main.rates = {}
        this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_code][rate_type] = {               //object
                main : room_index,
                rates : stateroom_index,
                rate_code : this.arrSelection.main.rates.rate_code,
                rate_type : this.arrSelection.main.rates.rate_type
            }

      let roomAdultCount = this.getRoomAdultCount(room_index, stateroom_index)
      let roomChildCount = this.getRoomChildCount(room_index, stateroom_index)

        if (!action && (roomAdultCount !== 0 || roomChildCount !== 0)) {
            this.minusUnitCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.minusRoomChildCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.minusRoomAdultCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.minusStateroomRoomAdultChildCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.minusRoomAccomCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
        }

        if (action) {
            this.addUnitCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.addRoomChildCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.addRoomAdultCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.addStateroomRoomAdultChildCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
            this.addRoomAccomCount(room_index, stateroom_index);
        }
        this.appendChargeMethod(stateroom_index)
        this.updateSegmentOneStatus(room_index, stateroom_index)
        this.buildBookingSummaryRoomArr()
        this.shouldResetAddons()
}
```

Comment: You are doing lot of manipulation in `this.arrSelection`, I see a lot of issues in this. Can you add a refactored code? From where are you calling this function? What is the main issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide a stackblitz sample project it will be more helpful but small check on the snippet there is small issue at the first two line of `onCountChange()` method

```
        let rate_code = this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_code];
        let rate_type = this.arrSelection.main.rates[rate_type];
```

you are using `rate_code` to initialize `rate_code` and same for `rate_type`. you need to define them completly before using them.